# access mapping inside mapping of struct in Solidity ^0.5.0

Tags: solidity, truffle, mapping, struct

I have a contract which looks like this:

```
contract a {
    struct Str {
        uint256 totalTokens;
        mapping(address => uint256) playerTokens;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Str) public tokenStores;
}
```

now assume that we have defined tokenStores as public and a getter method will be automatically allocated, is it possible to access a particular playerTokens 
value using a key from javascript? Any workaround possible in Solidity ^0.5.0 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do with a getter from `public` because the compiler doesn't (yet) know how to formulate the function with nested keys. I believe this is possible if you specific you wish to the experimental ABI.

A safer, more conventional workaround is to simple construct your own getter.

```
contract a { 

  struct Str {
    uint256 totalTokens;
    mapping(address => uint256) playerTokens;
  }

  mapping(uint256 => Str) private tokenStores;  // we'll make the getter manually

  function getPlayerToken(uint256 tokenId, address player) public returns(uint, uint) {
      Str storage t =  tokenStores[tokenId];
      return (t.totalTokens, t.playerTokens[player]);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How would you add a Str struct to tokenStores?

Comment: ??? tokenStore is a mapping of structs (`Str`). They could contain a struct. You declare the struct in the usual way and then cast a member as that type. `struct A { ... } struct B { A aStruct; } mapping(address = B) private bMap;`

Comment: `bMap` is a mapping of `B` structs. `B` structs contain an `A` struct.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function like this in smart contract to return values from mapping. You can call this function from your javascript code using web3 to get what you need.

```
function getPlayerTokens(uint _tokenStoresId, address playerAdd)
        public
        view 
        returns(uint)
    {
        Str storage s = tokenStores[_tokenStoresId];
        return s.playerTokens[playerAdd];

    }
```

Comment: yes this is a seperate function, which is pretty straightforward. But I want to know if it is possible to access from the automated getter function itself